# Generate lib from dll -> error on exec

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I'm trying to use the SUN LDAP C SDK (https://oss.oracle.com/projects/sun-ldapcsdk/). The zip include .h and .dll, not .lib so I need to generate .lib.
I use dumpbin.exe, expdef.exe (http://purefractalsolutions.com/show.php?a=utils/expdef) and lib.exe to do this for nsldap32v50.dll.
extract of the def file :

> LIBRARY NSLDAP32V50.dll
>   EXPORTS
>       ldap_abandon    @10
>       ldap_add    @11
>       ldap_unbind    @13
>       ldap_compare    @19
>       ldap_delete    @20
>       ldap_result2error    @21
>       ldap_err2string    @22
>       ldap_modify    @23
>       ldap_modrdn    @24
>       ldap_open    @25
>       ldap_first_entry    @26
>       ldap_next_entry    @27
>       ldap_get_dn    @30
>       ldap_dn2ufn    @31
>       ldap_first_attribute    @32
>       ldap_next_attribute    @33
>       ldap_get_values    @34
>       ldap_get_values_len    @35

Little code to test :

```
#include <ldap.h>
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LDAP        *ld;
    LDAPMessage *result, *e;
    BerElement  *ber;
    char        *a, *dn;
    char        **vals;
    int     i;
    int ldversion = LDAP_VERSION3;
    int debuglevel = 7;
    LDAPControl     **ctrls = NULL;

    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, &debuglevel);

    /* get a handle to an LDAP connection */


    std::cout << "Hellow World !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On linking I have one error :

> TestLdapSun.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ldap_set_option@12
>   TestLdapSun.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

The problem is, linker search for _ldap_set_option@12 but lib have _ldap_set_option.
To fix this error I modify the .h files :

Before :

```
#define LDAP_PASCAL __stdcall
#define LDAP_CALL LDAP_PASCAL
LDAP_API(int) LDAP_CALL ldap_set_option( LDAP *ld, int option, const void *optdata );
```

After :

```
#define LDAP_PASCAL __cdecl
#define LDAP_CALL LDAP_PASCAL
LDAP_API(int) LDAP_CALL ldap_set_option( LDAP *ld, int option, const void *optdata );
```

Ok, linker works now without any warning.
Starting the .exe file, ok but end with error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

I think this error come from my modification of __stdcall to __cdecl o the .h files but without this linker can't link.

Any idea ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: You cannot change the calling convention without rebuilding the DLL.

Comment: Thanks
If I can't change the calling convention, how I can change the call by linker removing the @** ?

Answer (score 0):

The export definition file does not have the entry `ldap_set_option`. Therfore your import library does not have a symbol to resolve the linker reques. The reason for the missing symbol in the .DEF file is most likely that the DLL doesn't import it.

Check you .MAP file what module resolves the external symbol `_ldap_set_option`. Lookup the correct implementation and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Sorry, the extract of .def file does not contain ldap_set_option but there is :
`ldap_set_option    @418`

Comment: `dumpbin /EXPORTS nsldap32v50.lib


Dump of file nsldap32v50.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name
...
           418    _ldap_set_option
...

`